# How to load Debugging Symbols for Unreal Engine Project Source Version build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I am unable to use any breakpoints in my **Unreal Engine4** project to debug the code, placing a breakpoint and running the project disabled the breakpoint automatically:

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
> for this document."

Comment: A little more info would be nice: Did you build Unreal yourself? What's your IDE and compiler? Did you build the code as "DebugGame" or similar?

Comment: @MaxPlay yes the source version I build myself and the IDE is visual studio 2019

Comment: When using VS, you can select a solution configuration. If you want to step through your code, you have to build the solution as DebugGame or DebugGameEditor. See [the docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/build-configurations-reference-for-unreal-engine/) for reference.